# How to convert a string "001" to int 001

Tags: c#

how do i convert a string of "001" to an int 001? using Convert.ToInt32() method or Int32.Parse() method gives the result as only 1

Comment: Either I misunderstood the question or you misunderstood the decimal numeral system.

Comment: why upvote? it's not a good question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1 is an integer, 001 is a string. If you are trying to display a 3-digit series as an id or similar and are incrementing you will need to convert your string "001" to an integer, increment it, then convert it back to a "0" padded string for display.

```
public string NextId(string currentId)
{
    int i = 0;
    if (int.TryParse(currentId, out i))
    {
        i++;
        return(i.ToString().PadLeft(3,'0'));
    }
    throw new System.ArgumentException("Non-numeric string passed as argument");
}
```

Comment: after converting the int to string and using the PadLeft(3,'0') method i am still getting the resultant string as 1 i.e. PadLeft() method is having no effect.

Comment: You are not converting your result back to a numeric type are you? To display leading 0s you have to use a string.

Comment: i got it, i declared a new string variable and assigned int.ToString().PadLeft(3,'0') to it. before that i was just doing int.ToString().PadLeft(3,'0') and then printing int.ToString() i.e. the value after padding wasn't getting saved. anyways, thx a lot for the solution.

Comment: Strings are immutable, they cannot be changed once created. To change a string you must create a new string - ie string newString = existingString + " more text"

Comment: A wild guess is the ID system is capped at 1000, so it needs a check for that too

Comment: Wouldn't the system be able to increment up to 9999?

Comment: The example only uses 3 places so technically the limit is "999".

Comment: why do u think that the limit is 999 or 9999, even after that it should increment. i just started with 001 because my sir asked me to do so.i think it can be incremented up to the last value permissible by the int data type.

Answer (score 13):

How could you have an int as 001?  You could format it as a string with leading zeros, but the int itself is just a numeric representation.  Keep in mind that the language needs a way to represent the int to you as a series of characters, and that it needs to be deterministic (because otherwise it would have no way to choose).  So the standard is to not show any leading zeros.

Comment: Besides, a leading zero means you're working in octal in most cases.

Answer (score 9):

You can't have an `int` with zeros in front like that - doesn't quite make sense. If the formatting is important you'll just have to leave it as a `string`.

Answer (score 7):

There is a fundamental misunderstanding in your question.  An int is a number, and in our numerical system, leading zeros on the left of the decimal point do not change the number and are therefore irrelevant.  In other words, 1 is equal to 01 is equal to 001 is equal to 0001 and so forth...   this may seem obvious, but it makes the point that 1 is the integer value.  001 is a string.

Answer (score 1):

An integer cannot store the value 001. The result 1 is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You need to elaborate on why you need the other zeros.

Whilst in byte form it will have a representation along the lines of 001 (or 0000000000000001), the runtime doesn't know which base you want to represent the number in, so the 2nd and 3rd columns (the other two zeros) are ambiguous.

Comment: actually i need to auto increment an id starting with 001 by 1

Answer (score 0):

an int will never be preceded with '0', only string is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Int32.ToString("000")` to format an integer in this manner.

```
string one = a.ToString("000"); // 001
string two = b.ToString("000"); // 010
```

but you cant use like a integer 001.